# Definition of residual scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

In page 161 of Fulton's "Intersection Theory" is written:

Let $D\subseteq W \subseteq V$ be closed imbeddings of schemes. Assume that $D$ is a Cartier divisor on $V$. There is a closed subscheme $R$ of $W$, called the residual scheme of $D$ in $W$ (with respect to $V$), such that $W=D\cup R$ and, moreover, the ideal sheaves on $V$ are related by

$F(W)=F(D).F(R)\qquad(1)$

Indeed, the inclusion $D\subseteq W$ means that $F(W)\subseteq F(D)$, so that every local equation for $W$ is uniquely divisible by a local equation for $D$; the quotients give local equations for $R$.

I can't understand this definition. In particular the condition on ideal sheaves.
How relation (1) tell us we can divide local equations? It is about product of ideals not of elements. I don't know!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can construct an affine open cover of $V$ so that on each piece, $D$ is cut out by a single local equation $f$. Therefore it suffices to treat the problem in the case that $V=\operatorname{Spec} A$ is affine and $D$ is cut out by a single equation $f$.

As $D\subset W$, we have that $I_W \subset I_D \subset A$ where $I_W$ and $I_D$ are the ideals cutting out $W$ and $D$ respectively. But as $D$ is cut out by a single equation $f$, this means that $I_D=(f)$, so $I_W\subset (f)$. This exactly means that every element in $I_W$ can be written as $f\cdot r$ for some $r\in A$, and this is what the text means by dividing local equations.

Comment: Thank you mr KReiser a lot. I think I understand now.

Comment: And can you tell me  how we construct scheme R? (i think)is it true that its ideal sheaf is genarated by 
$(f.r/f)=(r)$

on each open set of covering as you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: If this resolves your question, it is customary to hit the green check mark over by the votes to mark this answer as accepted. If this answer has been useful to you, it is often customary to upvote it using the up arrow over there too. If this doesn't resolve your question, please leave a comment indicating what's still unclear.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know I must do it.                                                                                        I just cant understand that which element($r \in A$) we should choose for generator of ideal sheaf of R. In particular which element $f.r\in I_W$ we should choose and then compute $(f.r/f)=(r)$.

Comment: Well, it may happen that you need more than one element: let $D$ be the $xy$-plane in $\Bbb A^3=V$ and $W$ the union of $D$ with the $z$-axis. Then $I_W=(zx,zy)$, and $I_R=(x,y)$. This generalizes easily to show that you can need any finite number of elements. What you should do instead is say that $I_R$ is the ideal generated by $g/f$ where $f$ is a generator of $I_D$ and $g$ runs over the elements of $I_W$. If $V$ (assumed to be affine) is noetherian, then this ideal is finitely generated, so there exist some finite set of generators.

Comment: thank you a lot. I should think more.